# Sharing internet connection.- Complex

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, network-protocols, remote-desktop

### Scenario

1 Desktop , 2 Laptops , one wifi router , one network cable . All computers are on win XP

Laptop A and Laptop B are connect to the network of wifi Router, they can access internet.
My Network cable is short so i cant connect it to the router Directly.

### Question

1- I want to Connect internet on my desktop . which come from my Wifi to laptop-A to Desktop    (by  network Cable).

2-I want my desktop to acesss Laptop B. (Do a remote Desktop Connection )

### How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Buying a longer Ethernet cable is the last option , but i want a workaround.

Comment: Buying a longer ethernet cable is by far the simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

1. Buy a longer Ethernet cable
2. Create an Adhoc network between Laptop A and the desktop
3. Install a wireless Ethernet card in desktop or buy a USB wifi-receiver.

Comment: How can i do 2nd Point ?

Comment: Couldn't tell you the exact steps in Windows XP. You would have to Google for it. I presume in would be in My Network Places then manage/share connection.

Answer (score 0):

Connect desktop to notebook.  Share your wifi connection on notebook(control panel - connections - right-click  wifi-connection - share). You can now access internet and files on another notebook (use \notebook_up in explorers address bar).
Question to be moved on SS.

Comment: Could you please explain basilevs ?